# Drops internet connection but not LAN connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, connection, internet-connection

I'm having a odd connectivity issue I can't solve. My desktop computer will lose its Internet connection for about 5-15 seconds randomly every 10 to 30 minutes. It's connected via ethernet.

This only affects the Internet connection but not LAN connection. I've done ping test and when outside sites are not available my computer is able to ping and communicate with computers inside our network.

This problem started when we got a new ISP and new router. Router is a TP-Link TL-R470T+.  But this connection issue only seems to affect my computer. I've tested other computers on the LAN and they're able to ping external website all day with 0 drops.

I've tried everything I can think of. Checked DHCP leases, flushed DNS, changed DNS servers. Router logs don't have anything either.

Any ways to troubleshoot or ideas are appreciated

Comment: Bad ethernet cable? try a different port on the router?

Comment: @criushspread well, did you report it to your ISP? remember if the issue is over the demarcation point cant be fixed by you and it should be fixed by your ISP. you will try to fix 1000 times without success because the real problem is not yours.

Comment: Considering it only affects this one computer, it is possible the NIC in that computer is going bad. You can uninstall it to force it to reload the drivers in the event they have become corrupt. Otherwise, I would try another NIC to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @Moab I tried switching cables with the computer with no problem. No change. Problem computer still has problems, other works fine

Comment: @CharlieRB bought a new PCI ethernet card for $10 and seems like the problem has gone away. Very strange overall

Comment: Great. Posted as answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it only affects this one computer, it is possible the NIC in that computer is going bad. You can uninstall it to force it to reload the drivers in the event they have become corrupt. Otherwise, I would try another NIC to see if it resolves the issue.